# How to create a duplicate test suite from an existing suite in azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

How to create a duplicate test suite from an existing suite in azure DevOps.

Suite1
-suite1.1
-suite1.2

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, currently there is no option to achieve this.

You can use the user interface to import a test suite from one test plan, within the same or different project, to another test plan in the current project. This action essentially copies or clones the test suite, creating a new test suite and duplicating any sub-test suites. The test cases referenced by the test suites are not duplicated, but referenced by the cloned test suites.

For more information, you could refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/copy-clone-test-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#import-or-clone-test-suites).